# Image Glow on Mouse Hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css, stylesheet, pixastic

I have seen this effect where when mouse is over an image, that image glows up. I am not talking about a border glow, I mean the colors in the image glow up. I found that there is a library called Pixastic, the glow affect can be seen here.

http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/glow/

Is there a way to apply this effect on mouse hover on the image? I am trying to make a button that glows up.

Thanks!

Comment: "I have seen this effect where when mouse is over an image, that image glows up." - where did you see it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to create a mouse over event like this:

```
$("img").hover(
  function () {
    Pixastic.process($(this).get(0), "glow", {amount:0.5, radius:1.0});
  }, 
  function () {
    Pixastic.revert($(this).get(0));
  }
);
```

The first function is triggered when you enter the image with your mouse cursor. The second function is called when the mouse leaves the image area. This is needed to reset the image to its initial state.

Answer (score 3):

Hi you can give the **Image Glow on Mouse Hover effect** with **CSS** as well as

**please check the live demo:-** http://jsbin.com/inenet/12/edit

[or you can read the tutorial of css hover effects](http://designshack.net/articles/css/5-cool-css-hover-effects-you-can-copy-and-paste)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like this?

[Zurb Glow Button](http://www.zurb.com/playground/radioactive-buttons)

For all your mouse adventure, I would like to recommend this

[HoverAlls jquery plugin](http://codecanyon.net/item/hoveralls-v13/full_screen_preview/1367456)

Comment: The Zurb glow button is actually made using css colors. I am trying to get an image (png) to glow.

Comment: HoverAlls looks really cool, but not really any glow affect there too. any other idea?

Answer (score 1):

As you see in the Pixastic example, the `demo()` function is called on submitting the form.

```
function demo() {
    Pixastic.process(document.getElementById("demoimage"), "glow", {
        amount : $("#value-amount").val(),
        radius : $("#value-radius").val()
    });
}
```

So you have you include `glow.js` in your project and call this function on hover.

```
$('img.myimage').hover(function() {
    Pixastic.process($(this), "glow", {
        amount : 0.5,
        radius : 0.5
    });
}, function() {
    Pixastic.process($(this), "glow", {
        amount : 0,
        radius : 0
    });
});
```

Or `revert()` like the [sample](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/) shows

Comment: this wont reset the glow effect after the mouseleave event

Comment: Hover is a shortcut for a mouseenter and mouseleave. Updated my answer